# Core Push notifications

Tags: asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please i have a question when i try to send push notifications to android device i can easily bind the keys which are senderId and ServerKey from appsettings which i get it from firebase console , then pass it through FcmSender and it’s work successfully.

```
var fcm = new FcmSender(settings, httpClient);
await fcm.SendAsync(deviceToken, notification);
```

My problem is when i try to send push notifications for ios device , i am always got BadDeviceToken but in the same time i can send push notification to this fcm successfuly from firebase console .
Is the mistake from my application server?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use CorePush for sending iOS Notifications. I am using CorePush 3.0.0. Previously I have tried CorePush 3.1.1 but it was giving me Json parsing issues

```
    AppleNotification NotificationMessage = new AppleNotification();
    NotificationMessage.Data = data;
    NotificationMessage.Aps = new ApsPayload() { AlertBody = "my body" };


    ApnSettings settingsApn = new ApnSettings()
    {
        AppBundleIdentifier = "com.iwish.developerscloud",
        P8PrivateKey = "p8 certificate generated in itunes,string without spaces, ----- or line breaks",
        P8PrivateKeyId = "10 digit p8 certificate id. Usually a part of a downloadable certificate filename",
        ServerType = ApnServerType.Development,
        TeamId = "You Apple Team ID"
    };
    var apn = new ApnSender(settingsApn, _http);

    apnResponse = apn.SendAsync(NotificationMessage, token.DeviceToken).Result;
```

I am also sharing AppleNotification Model class

```
    public class AppleNotification
    {
        [JsonProperty("aps")]
        public ApsPayload Aps { get; set; }
        // Your custom properties as needed

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public DataPayload_PushNotification Data { get; set; }

    }
    public class ApsPayload
    {
        [JsonProperty("alert")]
        public string AlertBody { get; set; }
    }
```